# How to specify which of two instances of the same type should be injected in which constructor argument

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Let's say we're building a workstation and are using some simple classes:

```
// two instances of this class are provided
Class Cable {

}

// this class requires one cable - each requires each 
// BUT we know that they are provided before instancing Desktop
Class Screen {
  Screen(Cable cable)
  {
  }
}

// this class requires two screens, which require each one cable
Class Desktop {
  Desktop(Screen left, Screen right)
  {
  }
}
```

We're using NInject to instantiate this tree of objects as a dependency to something else. The problem is - we already have two instances of Cable, each for each screen. They're going from two different sockets, so how to configure it?

```
// we get the cables from elsewhere
Cable leftCable = ...
Cable rightCable = ...

// so we add them as constants to kernel
kernel.Bind<Cable>().ToConstant(leftCable);
kernel.Bind<Cable>().ToConstant(rightCable);

kernel.Bind<Desktop>().ToSelf();

kernel.Get<Desktop>();
```

But it won't work - there are duplicate bindings.

Well, we can modify original constructor and use the NamedAttribute like this:

```
Class Desktop {
  Desktop([Named("LeftScreen")] Screen left, [Named("RightScreen")] Screen right) { }
}
```

and our kernel would be setup like this:

```
kernel.Bind<Cable>().ToConstant(leftCable).WhenParentNamed("LeftScreen");
kernel.Bind<Cable>().ToConstant(rightCable).WhenParentNamed("RightScreen");
```

Not really - I'm using it the wrong way. I'm having `Message: Ninject.ActivationException : Error activating Screen
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.` :(

Ok, I can create binding to method. But it takes much more code and kind of defeats the purpose of using NInject in this case at all. This is simplified example from real life problem.

Also, I can use property injection, but it has its serious downsides.

Comment: Instead of naming the `Cable` instances, you need to name the `Screen` instances. Currently NInject can't find an instance of `Screen` with a name `"LeftScreen" or "RightScreen".

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So the only way would be to create instances of two Screens with their respective Cables as arguments?

Comment: Yes. When using IoC containers, you always run into problems, if you need to inject several instances of the same type. The reason is that you have to define in some way where each instance should be injected into. Naming the instances is usually how it is done when using IoC containers. If you have a lot of those named instances, consider not using an IoC for creating this part of your object graph. Instead rely on manual dependency injection.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for making that clear to me :)

Comment: Why does the IoC container need to care which Screen or Cable is which? What's wrong with just setting up the bindings and letting the Desktop binding handle the dependencies?

Comment: It's used for WPF viewmodels, the viewmodels are for different panels, they are the same time but used for opposite actions (think left-right / entry-out). That's why "Cable" and "Screen" need to match.